# Multiple BSOD’s that led to bios not recognizing drives

Tags: boot, ssd, bios

Alright this one's gonna be a long one so get ready. I've had my computer built for about 6 months now and I've never had any issues. Here are the specs:

ASROCK B550M Steel Legend Motherboard

2x8gb 3600mhz Crucial Ballistix ram

Ryzen 5 3600

EVGA 3080ti FTW3 UltraCorsair RM750x 750 watt 80+ gold psu

Sabrent 1TB Rocket 4 Plus NVMe 4.0 Gen4 PCIe M.2 (which is used as my windows boot)

Crucial MX500 SSD (used as a manjaro linux boot)

The other day I was spending my time on my computer as usual, and I decided to run a game I like to play pretty frequently that I had had no earlier issues with, Destiny 2. After about 30 minutes playing, I got an error code from the game: marmot. That led to my computer completely crashing and I receiving the first BSOD I'd ever had.

The marmot error from Destiny 2 I learned to mean something was wrong with the game files, and it advised me to go into steam, and verify the game files. I rebooted my computer no issue and went in to steam to verify my game files. It got to about 50% where my computer lagged out and once again I had a BSOD. After restarting my computer again, I found my computer was not recognizing my M.2 drive and automatically booted to my manjaro drive, while it usually just automatically boots to my windows drive. I went into my BIOS to see if it was recognizing the drive, and it wasn't there.

I then shut down my computer and turned it completely off and then back on, and it recognized the drive. At this point I thought everything had been solved and I should try just uninstalling the game completely and reinstalling it because I thought it was obvious that something in the game files was messing everything up. Before I did this, just to check, I ran UserBenchmark to make sure it wasn't my cpu or gpu failing because of overuse or something similar and it went fine with no crashes.

I finally uninstalled Destiny 2 and literally as soon as I clicked the install button I got an instant BSOD. I then booted up my computer to see if anything was working, and then my BIOS was just stuck at the splash screen and I wasn't able to access my BIOS. I then turned off my computer completely and cleared the CMOS. After which I was able to access my BIOS, but this time, I didn't see my M.2 drive in the list of drives and my Manjaro drive which I had renamed had gone back to it's original name MX500 (or something similar, the name was just different than before.) I first decided to flash my BIOS and that changed nothing. I have not been able to access either of these drives and now when I try to boot up my manjaro the bios just freezes at post and doesn't boot. I thought something I could do is since I didn't have any important files on my manjaro drive I would just reinstall manjaro onto it. I put a manjaro iso onto my usb flash drive and plugged it in, and the BIOS did recognize it, but it still froze at post trying to boot into it. After this I decided to unplug my SATA (the manjaro drive) and reboot. This time it still didn't recognize my M.2 drive but it was able to boot into my manjaro flash drive. But this solved nothing because I couldn't install manjaro onto anything and it still didn't recognize my old drives.

As of now I have bought a test motherboard (GIGABYTE B550M DS3H) and test ssd (WD Blue SN570 NVME) to try out in my computer. I installed the ssd into my current motherboard and the motherboard recognized it no problem. (I also tried both M.2 slots in my motherboard for my old ssd to see if something was bad with the slots, there wasn't a difference.) I now have installed manjaro onto the new ssd which I am using right now to post this.

I have not tried the new motherboard yet but I do not think that is the issue as my current motherboard picks up my new ssd just fine. I cannot comprehend why one of my drives is not recognized at all, and the other one, when I have it plugged in, makes it so nothing boots. If anyone thinks I should try the new motherboard then say so but I am hesitant because I don't want to have to take the whole computer apart multiple times.

Is there any advice anyone can give me on how to get my computer to recognize either of my drives correctly and why this might be happening? Should I really just give up and try to get my data back through a data recovery center? I truly just want to know why this happened and how to fix it. Help will be much appreciated, even if it is a little because I understand this is a very tough and strange issue. Thanks